# Beamer with Biblatex: Bibliography entry font change has no effect

Tags: beamer, fonts, biblatex

I am using biblatex with bibtex backend in conjunction with beamer latex. When I set the color, for instance, bibliography entry title with

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=green}
```

then the title is rendered in green, as expected. However, when I use

```
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{shape=\scshape,size=\tiny}
```

or any other font property, like `family=\ttfamily`, nothing happens.

The setup for beamer and biblatex is as follows:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx} % pdftex hack fuer graphicx
\documentclass[pdftex,hyperref=pdftex,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{tw} % our special theme
\usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

[...]

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References}
  \frametitle{\bibname}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Hope someone can provide some insight into this mess.
Thanks Reiner

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Actually you are simply lucky that the `\setbeamercolor` does anything useful. beamer hooks in the `\newblock` command and this will in most cases not work with biblatex but only with manual bibliographies. Use the biblatex tools like e.g. `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{{\scshape\tiny #1}} `

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Want to make that an answer, so this question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are simply lucky that the \setbeamercolor does anything useful. beamer hooks in the `\newblock` command and this will in most cases not work with biblatex but only with manual bibliographies. Use the biblatex tools like e.g. `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{{\scshape\tiny #1}}`